# How can i override this vendor layout file with my custom layout file in magento 2?

Tags: layout, magento2, adminhtml

I have created a custom module in magento 2 and its layout file is located in
        `app/code/Learning/RewriteSales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml` . 
but the system loads the layout from 
        `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`
 instead of my custom layout file?How can i override this vendor layout file with my custom layout file?

Comment: i am telling about the adminhtml layout not frontend layout